# How to connect Google Nexus S to ADB manager?

Tags: java, adb, adt

I'm trying to use my phone to debug apps but I can't get Android device manager to show my device.

The deivce is Google Nexus S running Android 4.1 Ice-Cream-Sandwich and usb debugging is on when connected to pc.

I have tried the following without success:

1.Update S manager and install 4.1 platform

2.Re-install device drivers from phone.

3.Refresh Android device manager/reboot phone and restart eclipse.

I check for device in CMD and it shows it,but not in the device manager:

C:\Users\Brian>adb.exe devices
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached
3435EE3F028C00EC        device

Does anyone have a solution to get the phone to connect or have the same device debugging?

Comment: Your problem is almost assuredly drivers.  Often you'll have to uninstall conflicting drivers not just install good ones.  Start here and see if it helps: http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/

Comment: @Terry I added more info to the question...the device show in the command prompt but doesn't in the manager in eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured this problem out for anyone who is having a similar issue.The problem is that AVD manager is the virtual device manager so you need to specify to pick your device when running the project. go to Run Configs --> double click "Android application" --> click on "Target" --> Select :"Ask everytime you run app" , or your real device.

[image: Run configs]